# php accept 0.01 as input

Tags: php, regex, validation, int

I have a HTML form that has:

```
<input type="number" step="any" name="nearkm" value="000.000" onfocus="if(this.value == '000.000') { this.value = ''; }"></>
```

the input can be from 000.001 to 999.999

the search.php code to validate correct input is as follows:

```
if (!isset($_GET["nearkm"]) || empty($_GET["nearkm"]) || (int) $_GET["nearkm"] == null)
```

the code works fine for input including and above 1, however, if I enter 0.01 or any value less than 1 it fails the if condition.

My question is that is there a better way to check input, eg, using regex or another function?

Comment: (int)0.01 == 0 == null

Comment: `$_GET["nearkm"]` return a string. If you need to check if it is a number try the PHP function `is_numeric()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php  There are also `is_null` and `is_float` if you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you should be using the [intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) function PHP provides to safely cast a string as an integer.

Secondly if you want numbers like 0.01 or 0.999 you need a *float*, integers do not have decimals, so you should *actually* be using [floatval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php).

The problem you're having is that when 0.01 is cast as an integer it is rounded (to 0), which is loosely equal to `null`, you need to use `floatval()` and use an exact-comparison using `===` like so: `floatval($_GET["nearkm"]) === 0`.

Comment: To be a bit more precise: A float value casted to an int will not be rounded, but the decimal places will just be cut off.